# Differences between default config of BaggingClassifier in sklearn and hard voting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, data-science

I'm using Bagging classifier for SVM classification method using sklearn.

for running the code, I'm using the default configuration sklearn provides:

```py
classifier = BaggingClassifier(svm.SVC(gamma="scale"))
```

so the attributes would be:

```py
BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=svm, n_estimators=10, max_samples=1.0, max_features=1.0, bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, oob_score=False, warm_start=False, n_jobs=None, random_state=None, verbose=0)
```

As it is obvious, each of these ten estimators draws all samples and features.
So, are we just training 10 similar parallel models? After training the bagging model, how does it predict the new test query? By just voting among all these same classifiers? What is the predicted label in binary classification when half of the estimators predict 0 and half of them predict 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, are we just training 10 similar parallel models?

No. That `bootstrap=True` means we randomly draw samples for each estimator *with replacement*. There are equal no of samples in each estimator, and `max_samples=1.0` ensures that number equals original dataset size. But due to repetitions and absence of some samples due to independent drawing with replacement, the final dataset sent to each estimator are quite different.

> After training the bagging model, how does it predict the new test query? By just voting among all these same classifiers?

If base estimator supports `predict_proba` method, then class that have highest sum of probability among all estimators is chosen. Otherwise it is majority voting.

> What is the predicted label in binary classification when half of the estimators predict 0 and half of them predict 1?

If you look at the [`predict`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f6924/sklearn/ensemble/bagging.py#L630) function of `BaggingClassifier`, you will notice they use `np.argmax` function to find best class. And as noted in the #Notes section of `argmax`'s [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) -

> "In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices corresponding to the first occurrence are returned"

So `0` is the predicted label in that case.

Comment: Thanks, I have another question. Why should we use default bagging classifier while SVM is a deterministic method? Is there any explanation in using Bagging SVM with the default config(as I mentioned in my question post) instead of using SVM without Bagging?

Comment: This should've been asked lot earlier.

Comment: So? There is no explanation? does it improve the accuracy or reliability of the model? or make the model more general or avoid overfitting to training data set?